# Search directory of .htm files, outputting files that do NOT contain a certain string

Tags: html, full-text-search

I'd like to be able to search a directory, and sudirectories, full of 1000s of files, 90% of which are .htm files, and output a list of just those .htms that do NOT contain a certain string.

Best way to do that? (I'm not a programmer.)

Thank you.

Comment: How would you like to do this? Would you like to write a program that does it? Use a tool that will do it for you?

Comment: Which operating system?  If it's Linux this is trivial with find/grep. On Windows if you have Cygwin use the same tools. Without Cygwin there's still findstr.

Answer (score 0):

First, HTML is not a programming language nor let's you access your system's directories.
To do that from the browser you need a server-side language and a server environment. It can be PHP and Apache, or ASP.net and IIS, or others...
You can get started with [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) which provides PHP, MYSQL and Apache in a nice package, available for free for Linux, Win and OSX.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best off using your operating system's default folder/file search if you're not actually doing anything with the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [google desktop search](http://download.cnet.com/Google-Desktop/3000-2379_4-10328117.html)

You just need to install it, run it, set the folder and search.